# jQuery Array fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, fadein

I'm trying to fadeIn an fadeOut items in the array to a div. I'm trying to make this work in a fadeIn fadeOut manner. So first item fades in stays for 3 secodns then fades back out, then the next item fadein, 3seocnds then fade out and so on..... why is wrong with my code. Check http://jsfiddle.net/Fpu2E/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're using won't work for various reasons - having zero delay between calling `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` means you won't get the 3 second delay you're looking for between fading in and out, and that calling both functions lead to some strange effects with the jQuery effects queue.

A better option would be to use a recursive function together with [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) to do this:

```
var div = $('div').hide(),
    news = ['news1', 'news2', 'news3'],
    count = 0;

function changeNews() {
    div.fadeIn(3000).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
        changeNews();
    }).text(news[count++]);
}

changeNews();
```

A simple demo of this can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fpu2E/4/

Answer (score 2):

This works...

```
var news = ['news1', 'news2', 'news3'],
    count = news.length,
    currentItem = 0;

showNextItem = function() {

    $('div').text(news[currentItem++]).fadeIn(3000, function() {
        var element = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                if (currentItem < count) {
                    showNextItem();
                }
            });

        }, 3000);
    });

};

showNextItem();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Fpu2E/2/).

Comment: Thanks alex +1, though i think Yi's approach is simpler.