# Array print call not updating in sync with for loop counter Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and JQuery. I've written a series of ends to a paragraph that I'm attempting to rotate with one another using a `for` loop. Although I am seeing the number of fades, the text isn't changing on my site.

Here's the code:

```
var paragraphs = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"];

var rotateText = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
        $("#id").text(paragraphs[i]).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    }
};

rotateText();
```

Comment: Hint: `fadeIn()` (and its friends) isn't synchronous.

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle example for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. `.text` does not respect the standard animation effects queue
2. With the queue, the value of `i` will increment to 3 so it can't be used in callbacks.

This is solved by adding the text changing via a callback to `.queue` which itself is created via a function that uses the value of `i` as an argument so it can be used as-is locally.  All told:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    $("#id").queue((function (i) {
        return function () {
            $(this).text(paragraphs[i]).dequeue();
        };
    })(i)
    ).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

See it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/gBxgQ/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks foe the explanation. I'll be sure to familiarize myself with the queue function. Thanks again!

Comment: Also note that you can use `$.each` to iterate over `paragraphs` and create a callback which is a separate closure that you can use the index with each time.  You wouldn't have to create your own ad-hoc closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

this will print the text in circular fashion : foo - bar - foobar - foo - bar ..

```
var faderIndex = 0,

paragraphs = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"];
function nextFade() {
    $('#id').text(paragraphs[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        faderIndex++;
        if (faderIndex >= paragraphs.length)
            faderIndex = 0;
        $('#id').text(paragraphs[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
    });
}
nextFade();

<div id="id"></div>
```

Demo : [Working demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/N7Rhm/)

Also see : [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209954/jquery-array-fadein-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, sorry for duplicating questions, but thanks for the reference.